# How to add a colorbar title to a 3D surface image when using Plotly?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly, title, surface

I have been trying to create a 3D surface plot using Plotly with Python3. I am drawing based on the official case, but the case does not explain how to add a title to the colorbar.

I tried running the following command with no success.

```
fig.update_layout(colorbar=dict(title='Temperature(K)'), titleside='right')
```

The error display is:
Bad property path:
colorbar
^^^^^^^^
Also, is there a way to add units to the values on the color bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify it in the `go.Surface()` constructor directly, eg. :

```py
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=zdata,
                                 colorbar_title_text='Colorbar Title')])
```

Nb. `colorbar_title_text` uses "magic underscore" notation as a shortcut for `colorbar=dict(title=dict(text='...'))`.

See https://plotly.com/python/reference/surface/#surface-colorbar-title-text

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your comments are very timely and helpful for beginners like me！